# How to tunnel or serve multiple ports Via Cloudflare Agrotunnel?

Tags: server, web-applications, reverse-proxy, cloudflare-argo

I had two different webapps running on port `8081` & `8082` below

```
http://localhost:8081   --> app1
http://localhost:8082   --> app2
```

I want `app1` and `app2` to run on single Cloudflare  free temporary domain.

I had searched this and i found it can be done using a config file, please explain me from A to Z

Please explain or fix my issue, cause I'm new in this arena.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite late to answer but I hope someone else will find this helpful.

Considering you are on a Linux machine(or any platform for that matter), go to https://one.dash.cloudflare.com and then under Access-> Tunnels.
There create a new tunnel and on selecting the right platform, run the given command on the target server. This will start a Cloudflare service that creates a tunnel to Cloudflare.

Next, under public hostname, [considering you have added your domain to cloudflare] enter a subdomain and select your domain. You can also enter the path for that subdomain.

For service type, you can select from the dropdown[http in your case] and provide with ** localhost:8081** in your case for the URL.

Submit the form and Try it out to see it it Worked.